# Stucking in Ebbinghaus's Mathematical Logic Ch. 2-4

Tags: logic

I'm self-studying Ebbinghaus's Mathematical Logic. However, English is not my native language, and also I'm new to this subject, so I can't read it smoothly. I stuck in p.18, where the author said

> When we define a set $Z$ of strings by means of a calculus $C$ we can
>   then prove assertions about the elements of $Z$ by means of *induction
>   over* $C$. This principle of proof corresponds to induction over the
>   natural numbers. If one wants to show that all elements of $Z$ have a
>   certain property $P$, then it is sufficient to show that ...

OK, I know the definition of terms and formulas, and the calculus to generate them. But I totally don't understand what this paragraph is talking about.. Where is the word "proof"(in "*we can then prove assertions about the elements of $Z$*") in the paragraph unexpectedly arose from? What do the assertions refer to? What does the "proof" mean here? What things he want to prove?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The author is laying out the groundwork to be able to do proofs that will be about the  terms and formulas of logic.  These theorems and proofs can be about lots of different things. For example:

- The amount of left parentheses will always be the same as the amount of right parentheses (so this would be an example of a purely *syntactical/grammatical* result)
- Any truth-function can be expressed using only $\land$'s, $\lor$'s and $\neg$'s (this is an example of a formal *semantical* result)
- Some particular formal proof system is complete (an important meta-logical result about proof systems)
- Etc., etc.

But for all these you typically use structural induction of exactly the kind he indicates! That is, you typically prove something to be true for atomic terms or formulas (base case), and then use the recursive definition of how to create complex terms and formulas from other terms and formulas (step).

Comment: Thanks! I think I get it. Your concrete examples are very helpful.

Comment: Excuse me, may I further ask you that, did the author literally proved this structural induction?(i.e., reason why we can use it to prove things.) I know it is straightforward, just like traditional mathematical induction is straightforward, but I think it still needs a proof. However, from the parapraph on the bottom on p.18, I can't tell whether Ebbinghaus proved this. He mentioned the **complete mathematical induction**, but it seemed he treat it as an alternative of the structural induction.

Comment: @Eric  I don't have the book so don't have that passage in front of me, but it sounds like he isn't proving anything specific in this particular. Again, it looks like he is just pointing out that given the recursive definition of terms and formulas (which are both strings of some kind), we can use induction over those structures when latter on we prove specific theorems regarding terms and formulas. And I would see that as structural induction, though you can set it up as complete (strong) mathematical induction as well by looking at the *length* of the strings involved .. maybe he does that?

Comment: I don't know. The photograph of p.18 to 19 http://imgur.com/a/B6Vxq

Comment: @Eric Thanks! OK, so first of all, at the top of p.19 he lays out these 'proofs by induction on terms or formulas', which are proof *techniques* that are really just proofs by structural induction over the recursive definition of terms and formulas. And note that he *applies* that technique in the Lemma 4.1 (where c) is the one I mentioned in my Answer: that the number of left and right parentheses are the same).  ... end part I

Comment: @Eric part II. Also, on p.18, he says that he can also use complete mathematical induction over the length of the (syntactical) derivation of strings, i.e. the number of steps to create that string. For example, the term $f(a,b)$ has a syntactical derivation of length 3: Step 1:  $a$ is a term (T2). Step 2:  $b$ is a term (T2). Step 3: $f(a,b)$ is a term (T3 1,2). OK, so this is different from what I proposed, which is to do induction on length of strings. And while both methods can be used, it's probably not very useful, given that structural induction avoids having to talk about numbers.

Comment: OK! So the author means that (1)"*structural induction*" and (2)"*induction on length of strings*" are two parallel ways to prove some results that are syntactical, the reader can choose whatever he want (but as you mentioned that the former way seems more convenient.) The author didn't **proved** "*structural induction*" itself, but he did rigorously prove (2) by several words "*Since every elements of $Z$ has a derivation of some finite length, $P$ must then hold for all elements of $Z$.*". (So it seems that (2) is pretty trivial!)

Comment: Furthermore, he neither tried to proved "(1) implies (2)", nor proved "(2) implies (1)". And at the end why "structural induction" is valid, though it is intuitive, but the rigorous proof is not given.

Comment: @Eric  The proof for structural induction is pretty trivial as well though, since by their very recursive definition/syntactical derivation, every term/formula/string is generated following exactly the base and step cases. For example, the inductive steps $T1'$, $T2'$, and $T3'$ mirror exactly the recursive definition as provided by $T1$, $T2$, and $T3$. And as such, there is no need to prove (1) to (2) or vice versa:  (1) and (2) are fairly obvious in and of themselves.